# Rails: How to run before_update only for one changed attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, beforeupdate

In my model `Shop` I'm saving image url in `logo_ori` and use that to make thumbnails using `before_update`.

```
# shop.rb
before_update :run_blitline_job

private

def run_blitline_job
  # uses logo_ori to make thumbnails
end
```

However I found out that when I'm saving other attributes (eg: editing shop's profile in a form) it also runs `before_update`. How do I confine its execution when only `logo_ori` is saved?

I've tried this :

```
before_update :run_blitline_job, :if => :logo_ori?
```

but it still runs `before_update` if I already have `logo_ori` saved earlier.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
before_update :run_blitline_job, :if => :logo_ori_changed?
```

This will run the callback every time the `logo_ori` attribute changes. You can also use strings to implement multiple conditionals:

```
before_update :run_blitline_job, :if => proc { !logo_ori_was && logo_ori_changed? }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do a proc for that? `:if => proc { !logo_ori_was && logo_ori_changed? }` I guess it's a matter of preference, but I think the intention is a little clearer.

Comment: Yeah actually, in the case of multiple operands I would prefer a proc or lambda also.

Answer (score 4):

You are close, you want something like this:

```
before_update { |shop| shop.run_blitline_job if shop.logo_ori_changed? }
```

sources:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Answer (score 0):

its simple you can use [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) (checkout the documentation), it is available in all models in rails 3

```
before_update { |shop| shop.run_blitline_job if shop.logo_ori_changed? }
```